# Text to speech using javascript and translate_tts

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get my webpage to play up what it says in a text box when the user click on a link, but so far I haven't manage. I have tried with

```
        function listen(){
            var sound = new Audio();
            sound.src = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=sv&q=Testar";
            sound.play();
            alert(":D");
            return false;
        }
```

and

```
function listen(){
    var sound = document.createElement("audio");
    sound.setAttribute("src","http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=sv&q=Testar");
    sound.load();
    sound.play();
    alert(":D");
    return false;
}
```

I have tried adding `ie=UTF-8` to the link, and tried both with and without `sound.play();` but nothing have worked. I get smiley face from the alert so I know the function runs. Can someone please help me get this to work.

**EDIT:** I did a work around by using and iframe which I hide by using `display: none;` and then simply using javascript to change the src, not the best solution but it works... for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to do it :

```
var sound = new Audio("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=sv&q=Testar");
sound.play();
```

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work, I get the alert as usual, but no sound is playing.

Answer (score -1):

Now it's a bit more complicated, but still possible:
you need set up an user-agent string like a common browser and, more difficult, you also must provide a token into the GET request.
Some people managed to extract the token algorithm from the js code of the page, but it's quite a long work and at any time the algorithm changes you need to start again the reverse engineering of the cryptic code. 
So it's much easier access to a particular url from the same site that generates an XHR that shows the token you need.
A simple script with phantomjs and grep will do the job for you, details here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37221340/6332793